# Connection closed unexpectantly when running Riak's sample TasteOfRiak.java

Tags: java, connection, riak

I'm getting started with Riak, when I run the sample [TasteOfRiak.java](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/basho/basho_docs/master/source/data/TasteOfRiak.java) (I changed node port from `10017` to `8098`) I get a Connection closed exception. Here is the logs:

```
Basic object created
Location object created for quote object
StoreValue operation created
15/10/08 15:11:14 INFO RiakNode: RiakNode started; 127.0.0.1:8098
15/10/08 15:11:14 INFO RiakCluster: RiakCluster is starting.
Client object successfully created
15/10/08 15:11:14 ERROR RiakNode: Channel closed while operation in progress; id:321606938 127.0.0.1:8098
15/10/08 15:11:14 ERROR RiakNode: Channel closed while operation in progress; id:479772062 127.0.0.1:8098
15/10/08 15:11:14 ERROR RiakNode: Channel closed while operation in progress; id:1665941140 127.0.0.1:8098
java.lang.Exception: Connection closed unexpectantly
```

I'm running Riak KV 2.1.1-1 and using the Java client SDK 2.0.0. What's wrong with the sample?

Comment: does netstat confirm that something is listening on 127.0.0.1:8098, and if so, does the console.log show anything?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the right port for java client is `8087`, while `8098` is the http port!

Answer (score 0):

The java client for riak only connects using protocol buffer.  It does not support http.

As stated in the previous answer, you want to use 8087 because it is the default port for protocol buffer.